# Código em loop com condição não satisfeita

Tags: java, loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodigoDeBarras {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        do {            

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Informe os primeiros 12 caracteres do codigo de barras: \n");
            String codigo = sc.nextLine();

        } while (codigo.length() != 12); 
    }
}
```

Eu tô tentando fazer com que repita a mensagem e a leitura dos dados do usuário até que ele informe uma string com exatos 12 caracteres, mas está dando seguinte erro:
"variable codigo is already defined in method main(String[] args)"

Comment: Qual JDK (e versão do JDK) você tá usando? Pra mim este código não compila da forma que está, e quando arrumo pra compilar ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: JDK 1.8.0. No caso eu to rodando ele no cmd.

Comment: Cara, esse código não compila ._. a variável `codigo` está definida dentro do escopo do `do`. Não tem como o `while(codigo.length() != 12)` funcionar.

Comment: Não existe diferença entre "rodar no CMD" ou em outro lugar.

Comment: não seria melhor colocar < 12 ao invés de != 12, imagine o carso de alguem colocar 13 chars numa só vez...

Comment: Exatamente, a String `codigo`precisa ser declarado fora do laço...

Comment: @LINQ ele deve ter alterado e esqueceu de compilar.. apenas rodou da forma que estava, sei lá

Comment: Eu nao sei oq eu fiz, acho que rodei sem salvar, pq nao tava compliando msm. 
Declarei a string fora do laço, e tirei a classe scanner fora tbm. Agr funcionou!
Sobre o lance do CMD, eu to começando agr, foi mal pela noobada kk
Valeu pessoal, deu certo :D

Comment: hehe acertei @LINQ :P

Comment: @Jow Mas a resolução tá na resposta do Igor, por favor, marque ela como correta.

Comment: @Jow é o símbolo de check que fica debaixo do numero de votos

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Sim, já deixei meu voto =D Eu tava achando estranho, mas sabe como é, mantive uma desconfiança da versão.

Comment: Marquei como a correta. Editei a descrição da pergunta, que titulo eu coloco?

Comment: @Jow acho que está bom assim =)

Comment: @IgorVenturelli beleza, valeu.

Comment: Só para deixar claro, essa pergunta teve 3 votos para fechar como não estando clara o suficiente e 2 como erro de digitação (inclusive o meu), mas o StackOverflow só mostra aquela razão que teve a maioria dos votos de fechamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no escopo da variável `codigo`. Na verdade, esse código não compila.

A variável `codigo` existe apenas no escopo do `do`. Dessa forma, o `while(codigo.length() != 12)` não vai funcionar.

Declare-a fora e o problema será resolvido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodigoDeBarras {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String codigo = "";
        do {            

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Informe os primeiros 12 caracteres do codigo de barras: \n");
            codigo = sc.nextLine();

        } while (codigo.length() != 12); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz um pouco diferente na correção. Joguei a classe Scanner fora do laço e declarei a variável "codigo" fora do laço também. Teria algum problema, ou alguma outra diferença além da variável e classe ficarem no escopo local/global?

Comment: @Jow se colocar no "escopo global" (esse conceito não existe em Java. Chamamos de atributo/campo) precisa fazê-los estáticos, senão não poderão ser usados dentro do método atual (que é estático). É melhor colocar a linha que instância o Scanner fora do loop. Assim você cria apenas uma instância e não enche a memória :)

Comment: entendi. mto obrigado